# Array Level find & update in PHP multidimensional Tree Structure Array

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, levels

Here i'm using Tree structure Array for my php project. In this array i want find the array level in programming and update the array node level as one field in array.
Here is my array:

```
Array(
    [id] => test1
    [data] => Array([balance] => 0 )
    [has_children] => 1
    [children] => Array(
            [0] => Array
                ([id] => test2
                [data] => Array([balance] => 45)
                [has_children] => 
                )
            [1] => Array(
                    [id] => test3
                    [data] => Array([balance] => 78)
                    [has_children] => 
                )
            [2] => Array(
                    [id] => test55
                    [data] => Array([balance] => 0)
                    [has_children] => 1
                    [children] => Array(
                            [0] => Array(
                                    [id] => test45
                                    [data] => Array([balance] => 90)
                                    [has_children] => 
                                )
                        )
                )
            [3] => Array(
                    [id] => test567
                    [data] => Array([balance] => 123)
                    [has_children] => 
                )
            [4] => Array(
                    [id] => test79
                    [data] => Array([balance] => 34)
                    [has_children] => 
                )
        )
)
```

Array created dynamically. So i couldn't find that array depth and each node level. for ex: test1 as level 1, test2 as level 2, test3 as level 2, test55 as level 2, test 45 as level 3 AND test567 & test79 as level 2.

Comment: whats this `PHP Tree structure Array` what library are you using, this looks like a nested set, not something trivial to write.

Comment: i just have an array like this in php. I want to find and update node level.

Comment: What made this array?

Comment: Using mysql query data i construct this array.